# How to dynamic dir and locale in HtmlAttr in Nuxt3?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I'm using @nuxtjs/i18n plugin with nuxt 3 and after I install it I wrote my i18n(config) in the **nuxt.config.ts**
my code:

```
  i18n: {
    locales: [
        {
            code: 'fa',
            iso: 'fa-IR',
            name: 'Farsi',
            file: 'fa-IR.json',
            dir: 'rtl',
        },
        {
            code: 'en',
            iso: 'en-US',
            name: 'English',
            file: 'en-US.json',
            dir: 'ltr',
        },
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'fa',
    detectBrowserLanguage: false,
    langDir: "lang",
    vueI18n: {
        legacy: false,
        fallbackLocale: 'fa',
    }
}
```

after that, I use **useLocaleHead({})** and **useHead({})** in the default.vue(it's in my layout actually)

```
<script setup lang="ts">

const head = useLocaleHead({
  addDirAttribute: true,
  addSeoAttributes: true
});
useHead({
 htmlAttrs: {
   lang: head.value.htmlAttrs!.lang,
   dir: head.value.htmlAttrs!.dir
 },
});
</script>
```

but, when I run the project the dir and locale won't dynamic and change if I select another language.
the output images:
[image]
[image]

as you can see dir and lang attributes on html tag won't change. however, the content's shown as english.
can anyone help how I can develop it with nuxt3??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it using `<Html>` tag in my layout file:

This is the content of my `layouts\default.vue` file

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Html :lang="head.htmlAttrs.lang" :dir="head.htmlAttrs.dir"></Html>
    <Navbar />
    <div class="content">
      <slot />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const head = useLocaleHead({
  addDirAttribute: true,
  identifierAttribute: 'id',
  addSeoAttributes: true
})
</script>
```

I hope it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is just to add an html tag to your layouts/default file

```
<template>
   <Html :lang="head.htmlAttrs.lang" :dir="head.htmlAttrs.dir">
    ... the rest of your code in layouts/default
  </Html>
</template>

<script setup>
const head = useLocaleHead({
  addDirAttribute: true,
  identifierAttribute: 'id',
  addSeoAttributes: true
})
</script>
```